# What's "egg soakings"?

Tags: word-meaning

In The Simpsons [S12E11](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-simpsons&episode=s12e11) Moe tells Comic Book Guy about the offerings in his bar:

> Your choices are beer and, uh, **egg soakings**.

What is *egg soakings*?

Edit: searching for "egg soakings" mostly (only?) returns result about this episode.

Comment: [Chat to discuss whether "soakings" are a word in English](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99109/discussion-on-question-by-d-b-whats-egg-soakings).

Answer (score 2):

Moe keeps a jar of pickled eggs on his counter for the patrons. That liquid in the jar is what he is calling “egg soakings”.

> [soak](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/soak)
>   1 a. To immerse in liquid for a period of time: Soak the beans in water before cooking. (TFD)

In this context “soakings” is being used for the liquid in which the eggs were soaked.

Note that the liquid is likely brine, or vinegar ([pickled eggs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickled_egg)). “Egg soakings” is a somewhat unusual phrasing. However, it’s plausible that Moe would say this. Moe and the patrons aren’t exactly sophisticated or learned, so they likely wouldn’t know what the curing solution is or is called. Furthermore, I see that phrasing as being used for comedic effect. “Egg soakings” sounds pretty gross to me. :)

Comment: Yes,it is being used for brine, and it is not a word in English. It's just gross talk from The Simpsons. Yes, too, to brine, which is what I had said in my comment. I don't think it is so great, myself.

Comment: There are such things as [gari soakings](https://kuulpeeps.com/2019/08/foodies-up-your-gari-soakings-game-with-these-hacks/). I’m trying to find a reference, but I think the word is old fashioned, and using the “soakings” was something limited to poorer populations, so it’s proving difficult. It fits Moe to a tee though.

Comment: So far, all I can find are references to privy run-off... “The emanations from filth pollute the air— the soakings from it pollute the soil and the water in the wells.“ [soakings from Ngram](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22soakings%20from%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).